# How to use not logical operation in python

Tags: python

inputing an logical expression as string and evaluating, i'm getting proper output

```
str1 = "(1|0)&(1|1&(0|1))"
print eval(str1)
o/p: 1
```

But the same way if i'm including not operator as ~, the output goes wrong.

```
str1 = "(~0|~1)&(~1|0)"
print eval(str1)
o/p: -2
```

Is there any other way of representing not operator here to get proper answer.

Comment: The logical not in python is `not`.   `~` is the bitwise not.

Comment: also, why do you `eval`? it's not needed to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

These are not logical expressions but bitwise expressions. That is the reason why `~0 == -1`. Instead you can look for a parser that parses these expressions the way you want. A quick google search showed up [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467590/dynamically-evaluating-simple-boolean-logic-in-python).
Sympy seems to implement a similar thing: [sympy logic](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/logic.html)

> The logic module for SymPy allows to form and manipulate logic expressions using symbolic and boolean values

Answer (score 0):

`&`, `|` and `~` are bitwise operators.

For logic operators use `and`, `or` and `not`.

If your intention is to do logical operations, prefer to use the appropriate boolean values:

`True` / `False`

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = "(not 0|not 1) and (not 1|0)"
print eval(str1)
```

In python NOT is `not`

Ref : https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html