# How to evaluate python string boolean expression using eval()?

Tags: python, boolean

I get boolean expression like below :

```
string = '!True && !(True || False || True)'
```

I know `eval('1+2')` returns `3`. But when I am executing `eval(string)` it is throwing me error as in invalid syntax.

Is there any other way I can execute the above expression?

Comment: python doesn't use `&&` and `||` - you want `and`, `or`, `not`.

Comment: `!True` is not valid Python. The `!` operator doesn't exist in Python, use `not` instead.

Answer (score 4):

None of `!`, `&&` and `||` are valid Python operators; `eval()` can only handle valid Python expressions.

You'd have to replace those expressions with valid Python versions; presumably `!` is `not`, `&&` is `and`, and `||` is `or`, so you *could* just replace those with the Python versions:

```
eval(string.replace('&&', 'and').replace('||', 'or').replace('!', 'not '))
```

Note the space after `not` because Python requires this.

The better approach would be to not use the wrong spelling for those operators (they look like Java or JavaScript or C).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse boolean logic (in contrast to control flow) take a look at [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467590/dynamically-evaluating-simple-boolean-logic-in-python). It mentions [pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/)

> The pyparsing module is an alternative approach to creating and executing simple grammars

and [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/logic.html).

> The logic module for SymPy allows to form and manipulate logic expressions using symbolic and boolean value.

There also seems to be a [parser implemented with pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/simpleBool.py).

Of course you could also write a parser yourself.