# Combining list of Booleans with list of logical operators

Tags: python, python-3.x

This seems like it should be a simple one, but I'm struggling to come up with an elegant way of achieving it.

Ultimately I have two lists:

- One of arbitrary length `n` containing Boolean values, e.g. `conditions = [True, True]`
- One of length `n - 1` containing strings corresponding to logical operations, e.g. `operations = ['&']`

What I would like to do is map the string `&` to the logical `and` operation, and apply this to the `conditions` variable; `True and True` - yielding `True`.

I can achieve the mapping:

```
OPERATOR_MAP = {
    '&': operator.and_,
    '|': operator.or_
}
```

Leaving me with:

```
conditions = [True, True]  
operations = [<built-in function and_>]
```

The only way I can envisage applying the `operations` to `conditions` is to iterate, but I think this could result in violating the operator precedence a downstream user would expect. Is there a neat way of solving this that doesn't involve handling `and` then `or` precedence manually?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467590/dynamically-evaluating-simple-boolean-logic-in-python.