# Python Boolean expression evaluation against inputs

Tags: python

Is it possible to evaluate a Python Boolean expression against a set of inputs?

For example, consider the expression -

( A and B ) or ( C and D )

For inputs ( A, B, C ), the expression should evaluate to true.

For inputs ( B, C, E), the expression should evaluate to false.

Looking for some advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried with. [SO] can help you troubleshoot existing code. To learn more about how the community can help you, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: What have you tried ? What prevents you from using basic if conditions ?

Comment: I am quite confused what is the question here? Your example expression has 4 variables yet you talk about only 3 inputs in each case, also what is `E`? Also if your aim is to run that expression against multiple different inputs can't you simply create a function that returns the result of that expression and loop over your inputs?

Comment: The inputs are expression clauses that TRUE in a given scenario. So, E is another clause but my expression doesn’t use it. 

The real expressions are very large and inputs are run time True clauses. Hence, cannot use If conditions to solve this.

Comment: you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77064690/13520498