# Dependency Injection with Inheritance in Python

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, dependency-injection, subclass, base-class

I have a base class and subclass, defined as:

```
class Baseclass:

    def test():
        pass

class Subclass(Baseclass):
     def test():
         print("test")
```

In a class trying to create the object of Subclass, I want to inject the baseclass there.
How can this be done using dependency injection in Python?

Comment: Does this discussion help? [Why is IoC / DI not common in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461702/why-is-ioc-di-not-common-in-python)

Comment: I don't see an example there